Running code submitted by user in a secure way using Docker
I'm creating an app where user sends code with implementation of an algorithm. My goal is to run this algorithm and test its quality. But - the code sent by user can be unsafe and try to exploit system vulnerabilities. How to run it safely?
I was exploring Docker containers. How / Is it possible actually for a process to break out of the container if all the restrictions are set? I'm talking about rootless mode, resources limitations with cgroups, self-configured internal network, setting unpriviledged user, dropping all of the capabilities, preventing in-container privilege escalation, limiting syscalls with seccomp, using AppArmor as MAC, using code-scanning tools... Those restrictions seem to cover all of the possible risks, but is that right?
PS. can you please recommend any code-scanning tools applicable to this case? Users can send code in python or C++

Since Docker shares the host kernel, there's a range of possible attacks from that; and there are things like cryptocurrency miners that aren't "attacks" per se but you'd rather not run on your own.  This is an incredibly broad area, and I don't think Docker on its own is enough protection to run truly untrusted code.

So what would you recommend to use when there is a need to run untrusted code?
